# SVN child permission setting doesn't overwrite which is on parent path

Tags: svn

It looks like the permission settings on sub folders doesn't overwrite those on parent folders.
Here is the folder layout

```
/-01.Standard Assets
 -02.Opportunities|
                  |-01.RIF
                  |-02.FUF
 -03. Operations
```

Here is the authz

```
[aliases]
# joe = /C=XZ/ST=Dessert/L=Snake City/O=Snake Oil, Ltd./OU=Research Institute/CN=Joe Average

[groups]
# harry_and_sally = harry,sally
# harry_sally_and_joe = harry,sally,&joe

# [/foo/bar]
# harry = rw
# &joe = r
# * =

# [repository:/baz/fuz]
# @harry_and_sally = rw
# * = r
[/]
* = r

[/01.Standard Assets]
sally = rw
* =

[/02.Opportunities]
sally = rw
harry = r
* =
[/03.Operations]
sally = rw
* =


[/02.Opportunities/00.Templates]
* = r


[/02.Opportunities/01.RIF]
harry = rw
* = r


[/02.Opportunities/02.FUF]
* = rw
```

I expect the user "harry" can only access and see the folder 01.RIF but with the setting above it doesn't work. Instead Harry can always see 01.RIF and 02.FUF.

Please kindly advise.

regards

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
[/02.Opportunities]
harry = r
```

which is **not** overloaded later (which user-level operand) in `[/02.Opportunities/02.FUF]`. Thus harry can `rw` *directly defined* in `[/02.Opportunities/01.RIF]` and `r` in `[/02.Opportunities/02.FUF]` *inherited* from `[/02.Opportunities]`